# Filter SharePoint Page based on a User's Logged with javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

In my company's Sharepoint website, each user account includes Display Name (LastName, FirstName and Initial).

I need a selective View based on the User's name. I'm not using People Picker, so I can't use [Me] for filter by "Created by" or "Modified by". I will have a page where a user may have an approval section, so what I'm looking for is when ever the user appears on the form, display the item as part of the filter view. I'm currently using Sharepoint 2013 soon going to O365 SharePoint. Thank you for your inputs.

How can I do this using Javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "filter a SharePoint page" ? Filter the page content ?
Which version of SharePoint are you using ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SharePoint Current User View using JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277756/sharepoint-current-user-view-using-javascript)

Comment: @juaP, if anybody should have a chance to help you with this you need to type out every single detail about your problem, including that this is regarding an InfoPath form library

Comment: Rune Sperre, thank you so much. Again, I do apologize for my oversight. I'm not sure if still can help, I would like to find a solution to this. Or, perhaps, come up with another approach if my initial objective request may not be doable. Again. thank you for your assistance. I'm just trying to learn from knowledgeable individuals like yourself.