# SharePoint Current User View using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, view, sharepoint-list-filter

I'm running SharePoint 2013, I would like to have a Current User Filtered View using Javascript.

the [Me] would not be feasible because I'm not using the "People Picker" as the field type. I used a text field in 4 different text fields. For instance, Field1_Text, Field2_Text, Field3_Text and Field4_Text can different Users. The form will have four different approval process; however, I would like to display the form whenever one of those text field has the current user listed. The Current User Filter Web Part, only allows for one field to be selected not all four fields, so that approach won't work either.

A custom view will be used for the date of the item. For instance, "Created Date" Filter = [Today] + 15. The data would only be displayed if the current user is listed on one of those approval "Text_Field" as noted above and the form was created 15 days from [Today]. But, my main concern is the Javascript aspect. I'm trying to get myself up to speed on the topic. Let me know if there is anything else that I can provide. As far as the .JS code, I'm very limited since I'm trying to read and learn from many of the posting on this site.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you try to describe what you want to achieve by doing this? Why isn't filtering using [Me] working?

Comment: You should update your question to include those details - the more the better! How would you like the data to be displayed, any requirements there? It could be that a custom listing would be best here, but it all really depends on how you want to display it...

Comment: You should edit the original question and add the information from the comments, it will be easier for people to understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: Ok. Done. Any other suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a script editor web part to your view and add the following code. Adjust for column names:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 
    var bodyFieldContext = {}; 
    bodyFieldContext.OnPreRender = preRender;    
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(bodyFieldContext); 
})(); 

function preRender(ctx) {   
    var userName = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
    console.log(userName);     
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;     
    for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((rows[i].Field1Text != userName) && (rows[i].Field2Text != userName) && (rows[i].Field3Text != userName)) {
            rows.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This function will run before the ListViewWebPart is rendered and modify the rows. Any rows that do not match the users display name will be removed.

All items:

[image]

With filter:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the sample. I have followed your instructions and I added another "Field4Text" to the function as listed below. It doesn't filter by "FieldTexts", it only shows the entire list.                                                           
                                                                                                                                               if ((rows[i].Field1Text!= userName) && (rows[i].Field2Text!= userName) && (rows[i].Field3Text != userName)&& (rows[i].Field4Text != userName)) {
            rows.splice(i, 1);

Comment: Check the console, it is probably throwing an error and thus not modifying the rows. Maybe you didn't update the other column names?

Comment: I added screenshots to the answer

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 
    var bodyFieldContext = {}; 
    bodyFieldContext.OnPreRender = preRender;    
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(bodyFieldContext); 
})();

Comment: function preRender(ctx) {   
    var userName = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
    console.log(userName);     
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;     
    for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((rows[i].BCName != userName) && (rows[i].DirName != userName) && (rows[i].DXDName != userName)&& (rows[i].XDName != userName)) {
            rows.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
</script>

Comment: Any messages in the console? Try adding a "console.log('test');" somewhere to see if it is actually running. Then you can debug as well...

Comment: Perhaps, this may shed some light to my issue, the Text Fields are not being displayed on the page as your are, mine are part of the Infopath form. Names do not appear on the site like yours, mine are behind the scene. They are part of the form, so if a user is listed on the form, it would populate the information. I'm able to make it work with the Current User Filter connection only for one item. I can't have all four items as an option.

Comment: Ok sorry I give up. You might have wanted to mentioned the infopath bit earlier.

Comment: I apologize for the oversight.  I really appreciate your assistance and feedback on this.